# How to get a value of a column based on the id's given from another table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wanted to extract the value of a column given another column with id's of a different dataset.

DF-1:

```
ID  A       B
1   cat     22
2   dog     33
3   mamal   44
4   rat     55
5   rabbit  66
6   puppy   77
```

DF-2:

```
name   fav_animal
  x   1,2,3
  y   2,3
  z   3,4
```

I wanted to see the fav animals of x in a new list say name_animal.

code:

```
#storing all the id's of x frist
list_id = []
name_animal = []
for i in list_ids:
    name_animal.append(df1.loc[df1.id == i, 'A'].values.to_list()
```

Output:

```
list_id = [1,2,3]
name_animal = ['cat','dog','mamal']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check find `fav_animal` values with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `next` and `iter` is for return empty list if no name matched.

```
a = next(iter(df2.loc[df2['name'] == 'x', 'fav_animal']), [])
```

Then split values and convert them to integers:

```
list_id = list(map(int, a.split(',')))
print (list_id)
[1, 2, 3]
```

And last filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) first `DataFrame`:

```
name_animal = df1.loc[df1.ID.isin(list_id), 'A'].values.tolist()
print (name_animal)
['cat', 'dog', 'mamal']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function for example:

```
def get_names(df, df2, name):
    indices = np.asarray(df2.loc[name].values[0].split(',')).astype(int)
    return indices.tolist(), df.loc[indices,:]['A'].tolist()
```

So, for example if you want the `fav_animals` for name `x`:

```
list_id, name_animal = get_names(df,df2, 'x')

print(list_id)
[1, 2, 3]

print(name_animal)
['dog', 'mamal', 'rat']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.arange(1, 7),
    'A': ['cat', 'dog', 'mamal', 'rat', 'rabbit', 'puppy'],
                  'B': [22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
                  'fav_animal': ['1,2,3', '2,3', '3,4']})

df2.loc[df2.name == 'x', 'fav_animal'].str.split(',')[0]
['1', '2', '3']
```

Returns a list of strings. So you need to convert values to integers using map function.

```
mask = map(int, df2.loc[df2.name == 'x', 'fav_animal'].str.split(',')[0])

df1.loc[df1.ID.isin(mask), 'A'].values.tolist()
>['cat', 'dog', 'mamal']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for i in df2.fav_animal.tolist():
    print(df1.loc[map(int, i.split(","))]["A"].tolist())
```

Output:

```
['dog', 'mamal', 'rat']
['mamal', 'rat']
['rat', 'rabbit']
```

Alternative:

```
print([df1.loc[map(int, i.split(","))]["A"].tolist() for i in df2.fav_animal.tolist()])
```

Output:

```
[['dog', 'mamal', 'rat'], ['mamal', 'rat'], ['rat', 'rabbit']]
```